# Correlation functions with different momenta

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, greens-functions, many-body

In Mahan's "Many-particle physics" p.653 the following correlation function is evaluated
\begin{equation}
\Phi(i\omega)=-\sum_{\textbf{k},\textbf{p},\sigma}\sum_{\textbf{k}',\textbf{p}',\sigma'} T_{\textbf{k},\textbf{p}}T_{\textbf{k}',\textbf{p}'}\int_0^\beta d\tau \ e^{i\omega \tau}\langle{\mathcal{T}[c^\dagger_{\textbf{k}\sigma}(\tau)c_{\textbf{p}\sigma}(\tau)c^\dagger_{\textbf{k}'\sigma'}(0)c_{\textbf{p}'\sigma'}(0)]}\rangle
\end{equation}
where $c_{\textbf{k}(\textbf{k}')}$ and $c_{\textbf{p}(\textbf{p}')}$ denote fermionic operators on opposite sides of a tunnelling junction which don't interact with each other. The expectation value can thus be factored as
\begin{equation}
\Phi(i\omega)=\sum_{\textbf{k},\textbf{p},\sigma}\sum_{\textbf{k}',\textbf{p}',\sigma'} T_{\textbf{k},\textbf{p}}T_{\textbf{k}',\textbf{p}'}\int_0^\beta d\tau \ e^{i\omega \tau}\langle{\mathcal{T}[c^\dagger_{\textbf{k}\sigma}(\tau)c^\dagger_{\textbf{k}'\sigma'}(0)]}\rangle \langle{\mathcal{T}[c_{\textbf{p}\sigma}(\tau)c_{\textbf{p}'\sigma'}(0)]}\rangle
\end{equation}
Mahan then claims that this reduces to
\begin{equation}
\Phi(i\omega)=2\sum_{\textbf{k},\textbf{p},\sigma}T_{\textbf{k},\textbf{p}}T_{-\textbf{k},-\textbf{p}}\int_0^\beta d\tau \ e^{i\omega \tau}\langle{\mathcal{T}[c^\dagger_{\textbf{k}\uparrow}(\tau)c^\dagger_{-\textbf{k}\downarrow}(0)]}\rangle\langle{\mathcal{T}[c_{-\textbf{p}\downarrow}(0)c_{\textbf{p}\uparrow}(\tau)]}\rangle
\end{equation}
I understand that the factor of 2 comes from reversing the spins in each correlator yielding an identical expression. However why do we have the restriction that $\textbf{p}'=-\textbf{p}, \textbf{k}'=-\textbf{k}, \sigma'=-\sigma$?